# how to make my activity is the start activity?

Tags: android, android-manifest, zxing

I downloaded zxing project and I created a simple activity with a button. This simple activity should start zxing project when the button is pressed.
now my problem is : that i want this simple activity with the button to be the start activity
i created the following tags to in the manifest file as follows:

start activity:

and the downloaded zxing project has an activity that always is launched in the beginning and it has the following manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".CaptureActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <!-- Allow web apps to launch Barcode Scanner by linking to http://zxing.appspot.com/scan. -->
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="zxing.appspot.com" android:path="/scan"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <!-- We also support a Google Product Search URL. -->
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.google.com" android:path="/m/products
    /scan"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <!-- And the UK version. -->
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.google.co.uk" android:path="/m
    /products/scan"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Logcat output after changing my activity to be the launcher:

```
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
resume activity 
{com.google.zxing.client.android/com.google.zxing.client.android.Test}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at     
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2456)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1998)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at   
com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:178)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at   
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1157)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at  
android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
09-20 12:39:57.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22519):    at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
```

i just want to know how to make the simple activity i created is the start activity. in other words, where to place the tags of the simple activity in the manifest file of zxing project?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Which one is starting activity? or how to add activities in manifest file??

Comment: the first code with the name ".Test" is the start activity.

Comment: In your activity: Do like this:<activity android:name=".Test"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">

Comment: Please do not copy our app and manifest file. It leads to problems for us, and you -- like these problems. You're copying all kinds of config that are not correct for your test. Start from your own application, please. It is *not* meant as a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should remove

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

from `CaptureActivity` in manifest file.
and simply add

```
<activity
        android:name=".Test"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges = "keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name01" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

after the code part you have shown. I had not tried it. Let me know if it works?

Comment: @Amr how are you integrating both?

Comment: i did exactly as u posted but the app crashs

Answer (score 0):

All you should have to do is change:

```
<activity android:name="Leeder"
```

to:

```
<activity android:name="LeederTitleScreen"
```

If you want your title screen to start the game via startActivity(), you'll also need to declare your Leeder activity in the manifest.

Edit: Yes, you need the  section. It tells the system which implicit intents your activity will respond to. So in your manifest, the intent filter tells the system that it will respond to the android.intent.category.LAUNCHER intent, which is what Android dispatches when it starts an app (i.e. it tells Android to start the Activity when the application is started).

Here is the brief explanation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

your problem is quiet simple.

you just need to remove intent filter from the capture activity in menifest file and put it in your activity like you already doing. Because Launcher activity should be one in one project so if you want to launch the application with your activity then you should have to make your class as a launcher activity in menifest file with intent filter.

then it will start from your activity.

Comment: should i remove all the intent-filter tags from capture activity and place them in my activity? because capture activity has many intent filter tags

Comment: No, if you remove only that launher intent then it wrok`<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
` only remove this.

Comment: i did so but the app then crashs

Comment: what is that crash?? what is that exception??

Comment: And if you don't need those intent filters in your app then you can also remove those inter filters too. for intent filters refer this link.(http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: According to log, it saying that it founds null pointer exception in OnResume of CaptureActivity. please check there what is going wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

simple like this using  LAUNCHER

```
   <activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: i tried this but the app crashes...please note that, capture activitv has more than onr intent-filter tag

Comment: should i remove all intent-filter tags from capture activity and place them in my activitv?

Comment: i thin you jut change CaptureActivity with your require Activity

Comment: because its your LAUNCHER Activity